# How to populate bootstrap grid dynamically using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

So far I have fetched a list of objects from my database (each contain a name and description) and would like to display these objects in a bootstrap grid so that each object has its own section with its name and description shown. So if for example there are 5 items in the list and I'd like 3 items per row, then it would look like this:

[image]

And the grid would be responsive to the screen size.
I'm not very familiar with Vue and can't see how to do this without hardcoding the grid.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'app2',
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
// Fetch items from database...
}
```

Comment: you can use [boostrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout#layout-and-grid-system) is too easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use v-for and bootstrap styles:

```
<template>
  <div class="app">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm" v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.prop1 }}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'app2',
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
// Fetch items from database...
}
```